# How to display custom objects (with toString) in a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am rather new to Java, so please keep that in mind...

I have a `swing` GUI in which contains a `JComboBox`.
I want the user to select one option of an `ArrayList<Person>`.
Please note that I could also use an array.
I have used JComboBox before, but only with Strings.
The `Person` class has a toString() method that I want to use to get the text that should represent the object in the JComboBox.

When a JButton is pushed later, the selected Person object (the same one) should be added to another ArrayList for further operations.

I want the button to do something like this:

```
Person selectedPerson = (Person) myComboBox.getselectedItem();
```

However, I somehow need to get those Person objects into that thing somehow.
I tried to use:

```
myComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(aListOfStuff);
```

I even tried making my own model:

```
public class DropDownModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel<Person> implementsMutableComboBoxModel<Person>
```

but the setModel method wants none of that.

---

I have seen other kind of similar questions on Stackoverflow, but none of them answer my question. I've also noticed someone mention a renderer class or something like that.

Again:
I want an ArrayList to have its Person objects selectable in a JComboBox so that I can access the selected one with `Person tempPerson = (Person) myComboBox.getSelectedObject();`.

Do I have to make my own model class?

I pulled off displaying them in a JList. Using a custom model:

```
public class ListBoxModel extends AbstractListModel<Person> implements Iterable<Person>
```

Do I need something simular to that?

Is this possible at all?

Some examples:

```
myComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(s.getPersonListAsArray()));
cbRemoveClass.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(t.getClasses().toArray(new String[t.getClasses().size()])));
someOtherComboBox.setModel(new DropDownModel(dlModel.getList())); // trying to use my custom model
```

Comment: Given the [`DefaultComboBoxModel` constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html#constructor.summary) accept a) no arguments b) an array (i.e. `[]`) or c) a `Vector` - why would you be trying to construct one using an `ArrayList`? *"but the setModel method wants none of that."* Always copy/paste error and exception output! It sounds as if you're trying to 'program by magic' and that never works. Try to understand the messages the compiler or runtime provide. Check the API documentation for the methods & constructors used.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I already made an edit. Thank you for your comment. I don't get an exception, It won't compile (like I expected). Thank you for your comment, though.

Comment: *"all my code is on GutHub"* Few people will follow external links, fewer will trawl through a complete code base looking for problems. Post a [mcve] **here** as an [edit] to the question. The edit does not include the copy/pasted compiler error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm late to this, but this is the answer you were looking for:

```
JComboBox<ProtocolInterface> protocolCombo = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
HashSet<ProtocolInterface> protocols=this.myDevice.getSupportedProtocols();
protocolCombo.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<ProtocolInterface>(protocols.toArray(new ProtocolInterface[protocols.size()])));
```

Just make sure that your object (in this case ProtocolInterface) has a "toString" method that displays the text you want like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Why do I need a `HashSet`? Is it required, or will any collection (e.g. an `ArrayList`) work?

Comment: HashSet is just a collection that is used to ensure only unique items are in the collection. Notice I use the .toArray to convert it to an array which Combobox model requires.

Answer (score 1):

> Again: I want an ArrayList to have its Person objects selectable in a JComboBox

That is not how it works. The ArrayList means nothing to the combo box. The data needs to be stored in the `ComboBoxModel`.

So you need to add the data from the ArrayList to the model.

You write a simple loop to iterate through the ArrayList and then you use a combo box convenience method to add an item to the model:

```
for (each item in the ArrayList)
    comboBox.addItem( theItem );
```